# netlify-cli installs, but command 'netlify' not found

Tags: command-line-interface, netlify

I've installed the netlify cli (both in a local dir and my base dir, with and without using sudo), copying from the docs ~

```
npm install netlify-cli -g
```

but when I type the command

```
netlify
```

my terminal says

```
command not found: netlify
```

Has anyone else had this issue??

Comment: Try to narrow down if this is an npm issue or a netlify issue. Try `npm install http-server -g` then `http-server`. Also see if these installed modules appear in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` or `%APPDATA%\npm\node_modules` depending on your OS.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I realized that it may be something in computer versioning. I was doing this on my macbook 2013, which didn't work. Then on my iMac 2017 which did work. So not sure what to make of that but there ya go.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX 10.15.3 I ran the following to get it working:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also change the setting to
build command=CI=yarn run build
publish = ./build

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).